# Is GbM7 to DbM7/F also a chromatic movement?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I was writing a song in Bbm key.
And the chord progression goes something like.
Bbm,GbM7, DbM7/F

In this situation does the GbM7 going to DbM7/F
also consider as chromatic progression ?

If it is,why ?

Answer (score 5):

"Chromatic" suggests that what you're describing involves pitches outside of the key. The pitches of your two chords—G♭ B♭ D♭ F followed by D♭ F A♭—are all included in B♭ minor. Thus there are no pitches outside the key, and thus it wouldn't be considered chromatic. Instead, we call it **diatonic**, which is the opposite of chromatic.

To give you a visual representation, we can also say that "chromatic" suggests the use of accidentals. Let's look at these two chords in the context of B♭ minor:

[image]

Since there are no accidentals outside of the key signature, we would not call this chromatic.

Comment: Any reason why you specified Bbm rather than Db major?

Comment: @Tim Do you mean when I say that the pitches "are all included in B♭ minor"? I only use that because the OP stated their song is in B♭ minor.

Comment: Yes. The thing was muddied because the question was about two other (diatonic) chords, which both belong to both keys. Your reasoning is as usual - impeccable! Has already been +1d.

Answer (score 0):

'Chromatic' has a very simple definition - 'using notes outside the scale of the current key'.  If you're using a key signature it's chromatic if accidentals occur, it isn't if they don't.  (Let's dodge the issue of harmonic minor scales for now!)  I think you may have invented a different definition of 'chromatic'?